# Using handlebars with express and Backbone while maintaining SEO

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out how to implement Backbone with handlebars (on the server and client) while maintaining SEO.

Consider that I have a RESTful API in where the urls look like:

`/api/submissions/:type?/:category?:offset?:limit?`

When someone hits `mydomain.com/` it initializes my backbone here:

```
  var site = window.site || {};

  site.FeedSubmission = Backbone.Model.extend({

  });

  site.FeedSubmissions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: site.FeedSubmission,
    url: '/api/submissions/?type=tip&offset=0,30'
  });

  site.FeedSubmissionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      console.log(this.collection);
    }
  });

  var submissions = new site.FeedSubmissions();

  submissions.fetch({
    success: function(coll, res, options) {
      var feedSubmissionView = new site.FeedSubmissionView({
        collection: submissions
      });
      feedSubmissionView.render();
    },

    error: function(coll, res, options) {
      console.log('woops')
    }
  });

  var feedSubmissionView = new site.FeedSubmissionView({
    collection: submissions
  });
```

This works and instantiates the view with my collection, but if a search engine tries indexing the site, it'll obviously cause trouble because the rendering of the view is being done with JS.

Basically I want the best of both worlds: I want to use Backbone but also get the benefit of serving html to search engines. I'm **not** going to spin up a phantomjs instance or some headless browser JUST to serve my content to search engines. Primarily because it's too much overhead and flaky at best.

What do I need to do? Bootstrap data into some json and dump that into the page and override Backbone's `fetch` and `sync` to populate the models/collections?

Comment: You can read http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/ and http://www.backbonejsseo.com/

Comment: @jfriend00 One is a paid option (not using) and the other is using what I prefer not to (a headless browser redirect for Googlebots).

Comment: If you are building content in JS on the client, it simply won't be seen by search engines unless you redirect to build content on the server when access by a search engine.  As long as you're building the same content (just doing it server-side), this is allowed by search engines.  This is what LinkedIn does who is using server side JSON and client side templates to render pages for normal browsers and generating the same pages server-side for search bots.  There isn't another magic option.  Most crawlers don't run client-side JS so you only get indexed if the content is rendered server-side.

Comment: Meh LinkedIn uses dust which is much like handlebars except flaky (I've used it a lot). I'm going to just use handlebars and share templates between the client and the view (swapping out underscore templates for handlebars). I'll bootstrap my data into some json, and then on page load for each page render templates on the server then let Backbone take over.

Comment: What you're talking about doing is exactly what I was explaining LinkedIn does - they're using the same JSON and same Dust templates client and server.  Browsers render client-side for users.  Servers render server-side for bots.

Comment: Well I'm not talking about rendering server-side templates JUST for a bot. It'd be ALL users upon first page load. In addition, there would be a json context which I'd populate into a model and create a view based on a div already being visible in the DOM.